# Ubuntu 16. Проблема с HDMI

Tags: ubuntu, hdmi

Ubuntu 16.04: После перезагрузки компа не работает HDMI (к телевизору), а после выключения-включения работает. Почему так может быть?

Иногда HDMI начинает работать после того как я поменя разрешение экрана. Изначально выставил нужное разрешение экрана и все равно не помогает.

Прикладываю вывод команды xrandr:
**hdmi не работает:**

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1360 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1360x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1366x768      60.00 +
   1360x768      59.80*   59.96  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       59.99  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   576x432       60.06  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   320x240       60.05  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

**hdmi работает:**

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1360 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1360x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1366x768      60.00 +
   1360x768      59.80*   59.96  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       59.99  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   576x432       60.06  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   320x240       60.05  
HDMI-1 connected 1360x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 160mm x 90mm
   1920x1080     60.00 +  50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1360x768      60.02* 
   1152x864      59.97  
   1280x720      59.81    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x576i      50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: начните со сравнения информации, вываваемой программой `xrandr` в обоих случаях (работает/не работает).

Comment: @alexander barakin, приложил вывод команды в описние вопроса